# ng-if and select ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a view for angular+coffee and detected bug:

If category is selected, subcategory is not working.
When I remove ng-if it works.

Code:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row-fluid"><label><input type="radio" ng-model="banner.visibility" value="0" /> any</label></div>
                <div class="row-fluid"><label><input type="radio" ng-model="banner.visibility" value="1" /> always</label></div>
                <div class="row-fluid"><label><input type="radio" ng-model="banner.visibility" value="2" /> aftering</label></div>
                <div class="row-fluid"><label><input type="radio" ng-model="banner.visibility" value="3" /> category</label></div>

                <div class="row-fluid" ng-if="banner.visibility==3">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">category:</label>
                        <div>
                            <select
                                    class="form-control"
                                    ng-options="category.title for category in categories"
                                    ng-model="currentCategory"
                                    ng-change="shopBannerCtrl.loadSubcategories()"
                            ></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Subcategory:</label>
                        <div>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-options="subcategory.title for subcategory in subcategories" ng-model="currentSubcategory"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: always use object in `ng-model`. Since `ng-if` creates child scope your primitive binding will break

Comment: You _could_ replace `ng-if` with `ng-show`, as a workaround.

Comment: Is it resolved ?